# Unpin NFT metadata from IPFS from react

Tags: react, ipfs

I am minting NFT's and storing their metadata in the Infura IPFS. Is there a way to unpin the NFT from the IPFS from react?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the way to call [Unpin IPFS](https://docs.infura.io/infura/networks/ipfs/how-to/manage-files#unpin-a-file) api from Infura;

Since is not smart to keep the api keys in the Frontend(FE), I suggest you do this in the backend(BE)

FE requests=> Backend receive request then requests unpin => infura unpins

Comment: ok let me try working on that.

Comment: if you are using vercel maybe you dont need to relay this to the backend since the api keys are stored safely in vercel